# How do I run Python asyncio code in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-asyncio

I have some asyncio code which runs fine in the Python interpreter (CPython 3.6.2). I would now like to run this inside a Jupyter notebook with an IPython kernel.

I can run it with

```
import asyncio
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

and while that seems to work it also seems to block the notebook and doesn't seem to play nice with the notebook.

My understanding is that Jupyter uses Tornado under the hood so I tried to [install a Tornado event loop as recommended in the Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/asyncio.html):

```
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
```

However that gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1139449343fc> in <module>()
      1 from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
----> 2 AsyncIOMainLoop().install()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\numismatic\lib\site- packages\tornado\ioloop.py in install(self)
    179         `IOLoop` (e.g.,     :class:`tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient`).
    180         """
--> 181         assert not IOLoop.initialized()
    182         IOLoop._instance = self
    183 

AssertionError:
```

Finally I found the following page: http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html

so I added a cell with the following code:

```
import asyncio
from ipykernel.eventloops import register_integration

@register_integration('asyncio')
def loop_asyncio(kernel):
    '''Start a kernel with asyncio event loop support.'''
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def kernel_handler():
        loop.call_soon(kernel.do_one_iteration)
        loop.call_later(kernel._poll_interval, kernel_handler)

    loop.call_soon(kernel_handler)
    try:
        if not loop.is_running():
            loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

and in the next cell I ran:

```
%gui asyncio
```

That worked but I don't really understand why and how it works. Can someone please explain that to me?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**EDIT FEB 21st, 2019: Problem Fixed**

> This is no longer an issue on the latest version of Jupyter Notebook. Authors of Jupyter Notebook detailed the case [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/ipython-7-0-async-repl-a35ce050f7f7).

Answer below was the original response that was marked correct by the op.

---

This was posted quite a bit ago, but in case other people are looking for an explanation and solution to the problem of running asynchronous code inside Jupyter Notebook;

Jupyter's Tornado 5.0 update bricked asyncio functionalities after the addition of its own asyncio event loop:

[image: Running on shell.]
[image: Running on JupyterNotebook.]

Thus, for any asyncio functionality to run on Jupyter Notebook you **cannot** invoke a `loop.run_until_complete(...)`, since the loop you will receive from `asyncio.get_event_loop()` will be active.

Instead, you must either add the task to the current event loop:

```py
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(some_async_function())
```

Or get the results via `run_coroutine_threadsafe`:

```py
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(some_async_function(), loop)
```

Comment: Is there any document for this behavior?

Comment: Really helpful thanks. + Does anything need to be closed in the above or is it complete as is?

Comment: @QHarr If you close the loop, then Jupyter stops working.

Comment: notice this answer is not anymore up to date. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53581739/8784382) is

Comment: @GiorgioBalestrieri Updated post.

Answer (score 81):

This is no longer an issue in the latest jupyter release!

https://blog.jupyter.org/ipython-7-0-async-repl-a35ce050f7f7

Just write an async function, and then await it directly in a jupyter cell.

```
async def fn():
  print('hello')
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print('world')

await fn()
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the command to apply, I was kinda stuck using the old workaround :)

Comment: From all others solution, this is the most elegant one!

Answer (score 23):

My aha moment with Asyncio in Jupyter looks like this:

```
import time,asyncio

async def count():
    print("count one")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("count four")

async def count_further():
    print("count two")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("count five")

async def count_even_further():
    print("count three")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("count six")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count_further(), count_even_further())

s = time.perf_counter()
await main()
elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
print(f"Script executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

Output:

```
count one
count two
count three
count four
count five
count six
Script executed in 1.00 seconds.
```

Originally from here, but the example was not clear for me at first:
https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Answer (score 11):

just use [`%autoawait`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=autoawait#magic-autoawait) magic command,

eg :

```py
%autoawait asyncio
```

```py
await some_function()
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me, if it does for others this should be the right answer.

Comment: this did things for me

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the issue of not being able to run asyncio code in a Jupyter notebook. The issue is discussed here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397

I tried one of the solutions in the discussion and it solved the issue so far.

`pip3 install tornado==4.5.3`

This replaced tornado version 5.x that was installed by default.

The asyncio code in a Jupyter notebook then ran as expected.

Comment: Were you able to rerun jupyter cell with async code?

Comment: Yes. So far all is working as expected. I had to comment out some `loop.close()`.

Comment: So, only removing loop.close guarantees rerunability?

Comment: I am unqualified say if it guarantees rerunability. It functioned as I expected in the particular context in which I was working. RuntimeErrors went away after downgrading to tornado 4.5.3.