# Start asyncio loop from running loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to create a Runner class that can asynchronously runs multiple jobs and return the results one all jobs are completed.
Here is the dummy code snippet which I already have

```py
import asyncio

class Runner:
  def __init__(self):
    self.jobs_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

  async def slow_process(self, *args):
    ...  # run slow proces with args
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return "result"

  def batch_run(self, count, *args):
    results = self.jobs_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
      *[self.slow_process(*args) for _ in range(count)],
      loop=self.jobs_loop,
      return_exceptions=True
    ))
    return results

runner = Runner()
print(runner.batch_run(10))
```

When the `batch_run` is called, it schedules `count` jobs and blocks until finished.
This, however, doesn't work when called from a running event loop raising
`RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running`

How can I make `batch_run` work when called from existing event loop (e.g. Jupyter Console) as well as being callable from outside of the event loop.

**EDIT**

Ideally the function would look like this

```py
def batch_run(self, count, *args):
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  jobs = asyncio.gather(...)
  if not loop.is_running():
    return loop.run_until_complete(jobs)
  else:
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(jobs, loop=loop)
    # loop.wait_until_completed(future)
    return future.result()
```

if only `loop.wait_until_completed` existed.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518874/how-do-i-run-python-asyncio-code-in-a-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Not really a duplicate. This problem is not strictly related to the Jupyter console but is more generic question about how to make a function callable from both within and without asyncio loop.

Comment: What about passing the loop at the class constructor?
There is a reason that `batch_run` is not async as well?