# My code says that it is unable to close a running loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I made a code but it gives error unable to close a running loop

Code is

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_response(query):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(
            f'https://some-random-api.ml/chatbot?message={query}'
        ) as resp:
            return (await resp.json()),['response']
    
#using an event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Task = asyncio.gather(*[get_response('world') for _ in range(500)])

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(Task)
finally:
    loop.close()
```

**Please modify the code for me because I'm a newly developer**

***I will be highly obliged if you help me out***

Comment: Looks like an instance of [this aiohttp issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324).

Answer (score 1):

Here's fully working example:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


_sem = None


async def get_response(query):
    async with _sem:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
            async with ses.get(f'http://httpbin.org/get?test={query}') as resp:
                return (await resp.json())['args']


async def main():
    global _sem
    _sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)  # read https://stackoverflow.com/q/48483348/1113207

    return await asyncio.gather(*[get_response(i) for i in range(20)])

   
res = asyncio.run(main())
print(res)
```

Comment: Hey mikhail we can't call a loop with a existing loop

Comment: @Reejit you're probably running the code using Jupyter Notebook? If the case, just replace `res = asyncio.run(main())` with `res = await main()`. [Jupyter handles the event loop automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53581739/1113207).

Comment: Hey mikhail it says the await is outside

Comment: @Reejit ok, what if you replace `res = asyncio.run(main())` with `res = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` ?

Comment: Could you help me

Comment: @Reejit Could you provide full information about your environment (how you run your script) and any other source code if you have it along with snippet from the question.

Comment: Yes i use code from GitHub link is https://github.com/reejit/Chat-Bot-ENG and i run it on heroku

Comment: please help me i need your help

Comment: @Reejit would you kindly add a new question on StackOverflow? It'll be easier to find the problem this way. In this question specify kindly what concrete code you run and a concrete command you run code with.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) function to run the top-level entry point `main()` function:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_response(query):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
        async with ses.get(
                f'https://httpbin.org/json'
        ) as resp:
            return (await resp.json()), ['response']


async def main():
    res = await asyncio.gather(*[get_response('world') for _ in range(500)])

asyncio.run(main())
```